How a SpringBoot project sets the time zone for each request
I have a SpringBoot project right now, and there is already a lot of business code set to get the time, such as LocalDate.now(),LocalDateTime.now(),new Date(),new DateTime() .....
I now want to set a timezone for each request, so that the business code will perform the time fetch based on the timezone, but I don't want to change the business code because it's just too much!
I tried AspectJ for intercepting static methods, but found that it can only intercept static methods defined by itself, not static methods of JDK packages such as LocalDateTime
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ControllerAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.pkslow.springboot.controller..*.*(..))")
    private void testControllerPointcut() {

    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* java.time.LocalDateTime.now())")
    private void testControllerPointcut1() {

    }

    @Around("testControllerPointcut1()")
    public Object etst1(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        log.info("request");
        return LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
    }
}



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Slf4j
public class TestController {

    private final TestService testService;

    public TestController(TestService testService) {
        this.testService = testService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
        return "Hello, pkslow.";
    }
}

I cant intercept calls to JDK classes with AspectJ

This question is similar to: set timezone per request in spring. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, ideally a project on GitHub. Thank you. P.S.: We do not need your original code, just a minimal, generic version reproducing the problem. You can insert different ways to get/set the date/time. When I see the code, I maybe also have an idea for you how to intercept calls to JDK classes with AspectJ.

Your first paragraph is too vague.  Example code is needed, for us to understand what you are trying to change.  Please edit your question and add that example code.

@kriegaex  I have updated my description, please help me!

@VGR I have updated my description, please help me!

@Mohamedaminebenhassen Sorry, the question you provided does not solve my problem. I want to set the time zone for each request without changing my business code.

You need to switch from proxy-based Spring AOP to native AspectJ. Please remember to remove @Component from your native AspectJ aspect. Then, switch from execution(..) to call(..) pointcut in order to weave into the call site rather than the called method. Like you said, the called method is in the JDK and therefore unavailable for weaving.
Disclaimer: AspectJ is not a tool to patch up problematic code for developers who are simply too lazy to refactor. That there are many places in the code where you need to refactor is not a reason not to do it, because any decent IDE has regex search & replace, which should make global changes like that quite easy. IntelliJ IDEA even has structural search & replace which is even more powerful, albeit a bit complicated to use. But regex s&r should be enough. You could also factor out all those different calls to date/time classes into a utility class and, if any need to adjust it arises, change the code in a single place. That you can patch up things here with AspectJ does not necessarily mean that you should do so.

Thanks your help! I try call() expression is sussceed!

I have a another question, How aspectJ other package utils static method?
For example: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isNotBlank(..)

Firstly, I do not understand the whole sentence of your question. Secondly, if you have a new question, just ask a new question instead of hijacking an old one via comment. If tagged correctly, I will find it. Thank you.
